# How to have HTML inside a Ruby on Rails flash[:symbol]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, flash, hyperlink

I wanted to display a link inside a flash[:success], like so.

```
if @potatoes.present?
  flash[:success] ='Something something went well.<br/>
  Click <a href=" #{ potatoes_path(@potato_one) } ">here<a/> to see.'
```

But inside the flash it's displayed as simply a string.

How can I have actual HTML inside the flash, while being able to display the link?

Comment: If you are constructing the string yourself and it doesn't include user input you can use `raw "..."` or `"...".html_safe`.

Comment: But with .html_safe I'm not begin able to display the link (read: parse ruby) inside

Comment: You can't use string interpolation with a single-quoted string. Use double quotes (and escape your double quotes inside), or use a delimited string literal like `%q{this is my string #{potatoes_path}}`.

Comment: Sorry, I could've sworn I post. It worked, thanks. :)